# 18.04 not recognizing internet connection

Tags: internet, connection

I have two computers with 18.04 loaded and neither recognizes that they are connected to the internet. All other internet activity works as it should but even when I installed the OS, it would not download updates because it said I should check my internet connection, though the connection showed active in the status pulldown. 
Seems to be a bug in 18.04.
Will 18.10 fix this?